# Jquery Cycle 2 different slideshow sync

Tags: jquery, slideshow, synchronization, cycle

I'm new to this place, but I've been relatively new at coding javascript/jquery but I've been working with  jquery cycle, and attempting two slide shows running at the same time. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow1').cycle({ //first slide
    fx: 'fade',
    containerResize: false, //for autoresizing using CSS
    slideResize: false, //for autoresizing using CSS
    fit: 1, //for autoresizing using CSS
    speed:   2000, 
    timeout: 5000, 
    after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
      $('.slideshow2').cycle('next');
}
});
$('.slideshow2').cycle({
    speed:   2000, 
    timeout: 0, 
});
```

It works for the most part, but I noticed it does not work in Opera, and is there a way for Opera to run this? I also need to inform you guys that the code is for two different slideshows, one slideshow with auto resizing built in, reliant on the browser's window and CSS. The second is just a simple, none resizing slideshow. My obvious question is how to get it running in Opera (if I'm using the correct code), and would there be a more optimized way this would work?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the updated version of the jQuery Cycle plugin: [Cycle2](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/)